# How to suppress Jenkins groovy Logs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to execute Jenkins checkout command to checkout source files from subversion repository. When I execute command on a new workspace, it will display complete logs of checkedout files. Is there a option to disable logs and enable only when it is required?

Comment: Do you use shell/batch or the pipeline?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a quiet checkout improvement is in the works, but not yet released.

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-14541

Comment: Thank you Joey. Do we have some option to suppress logs from all the groovy commands? like enable/disable debug logs.